# Writing a python code for finding perfect roots

Tags: python

I wrote a program to find the perfect root of a number as long as it lies between 2 and 6 and print a message when there isn't an answer.

My problem is trying to generate an accurate print statement for when the integer has no perfect root between 2 and 6 (say 400), it prints the perfect square is 20 together with the error code 
Here's the code

```
# Get an integer and output it's root and power such that root raised to the power equals the input integer and 0 < power < 6.
#Get an integer imput from the user
integer = int(input("Enter an integer "))

#check if integer is a perfect square
counter = 0
while counter ** 2 < abs(integer):
    counter += 1
if counter ** 2 == abs(integer):
    print("Square root of ", integer, " is", counter )

# cheacking if integer is a perfect cube
counter = 0
while counter ** 3 < abs(integer):
    counter += 1
if counter ** 3 == abs(integer):
        print("Cube root of ", integer, " is", counter)

#checking if integer is a perfect fourth root      
counter = 0
while counter ** 4 < abs(integer):
    counter += 1
if counter ** 4 == abs(integer):
        print("fourth root of ", integer, " is", counter)

# checking if integer is a perfect fifth root
counter = 0
while counter ** 5 < abs(integer):
    counter += 1
if counter ** 5 == abs(integer):
        print("fifth root of ", integer, " is", counter)

# checking if integer is a perfect sixth root
counter = 0
while counter ** 6 < abs(integer):
    counter += 1
if counter ** 6 == abs(integer):
        print("sixth root of ", integer, " is", counter)

                    print("This integer has no perfext root")

# # A print statement for when the integers has no perfect such that 0 < pwr < 6

if  counter ** 2 != abs(integer) and counter ** 3 != abs(integer) and counter ** 4 != abs(integer) and counter ** 5 != abs(integer) and counter ** 6 != abs(integer):
        print("This integer has no perfext root")
```

Comment: Instead of using just if statements, use if, elif and finally else if there is no perfect root

Comment: One way you could clean this up is by looping over powers: `for pwr in range(2, 7): counter = 0; while counter ** pwr ...`. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. It would help to make a [mre].

Comment: Also this line is not properly indented: `print("This integer has no perfext root")`

Comment: Thank you for answering.... I found your answer very helpful